# What does this line do? [export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=”$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/]

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, unix

I'm trying to get MySQL-python working on my mac. I have to put this line in the terminal to fix an error, specifically "_mysql.so image not found". The source of this line tells me I should put it in my .profile for it to stick permanently.

I'm interested in learning what actually caused the error in the first place instead of just a quick fix. What exactly does this line do?

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=”$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appends `/usr/local/mysql/lib/` to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> ```
>           This is a colon separated list of directories  that  contain  libraries.  The  dynamic  linker
>           searches  these  directories before it searches the default locations for libraries. It allows
>           you to test new versions of existing libraries.
>
>           For each library that a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for it  in  each  directory  in
>           DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  in  turn.  If  it still can't find the library, it then searches DYLD_FALL-
>           BACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn.
>
>           Use the -L option to otool(1).  to discover the frameworks and shared libraries that the  exe-
>           cutable is linked against.
> ```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html

PS: presumably you've lost a closing double quote char somewhere

Comment: Thanks! While I was researching this, I came across a couple places that are supposedly similar with .profile, such as bash_profile and bash_rc. Is there a place where I can read up on the differences of these files?

Comment: @Wesley: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html